# Running jshint with rhino

Tags: javascript, debugging, rhino, jshint

I'm moving from checking files with jslint to jshint but the command line statement doesn't seem to work.

For jslint I used the command `rhino /home/mrtest/Desktop/jslint.js browser.js` which worked. I tried the same thing with `rhino /home/mrtest/Desktop/jshint.js browser.js` which didn't do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `rhino.js` file in the `env` directory of the full codebase: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/

e.g. `rhino /home/mrtest/Desktop/jshint/env/rhino.js browser.js`

Comment: Not quite. You have to concatenate `rhino.js` and `jshint.js`. The jshint distribution contains a Makefile that does this. Calling `make rhino` creates a file `build/jshint-rhino.js`. Use this file: `rhino /home/mrtest/Desktop/jshint/build/jshint-rhino.js browser.js`

Answer (score 2):

**Installing JsHint on Ubuntu 10.04**

*Assumes rhino is already installed.*

1. Download latest jshint master (tar.gz) from https://github.com/jshint/jshint/archives/master
2. Untar into ~/bin/
3. `cd ~/bin/jshint-jshint-09e24d8`
4. `make rhino`

Can now use:

`~/bin/jshint-jshint-09e24d8/build/jshint-rhino.js MyJsFile.js`

or more conveniently:

`alias jshint='~/bin/jshint-jshint-09e24d8/build/jshint-rhino.js'`

`$ jshint MyJsFile.js`

The same will work on most Linux flavours.